# Meteor JS loads first without template: gives "null" error

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, meteor

I am trying to use this : [AnimatedHeaderBackgrounds](http://tympanus.net/Development/AnimatedHeaderBackgrounds/) in a Meteor App.

Since, we do not have to load scripts using the script tag and they just render by meteor and No css files issues too, Meteor renders JS first before the template is loaded, and hence results in an error: Cannot read property of "null" in the console.

Here's the JS file:

```
(function() {

    var width, height, largeHeader, canvas, ctx, points, target, animateHeader = true;

    // Main
    initHeader();
    initAnimation();
    addListeners();

    function initHeader() {
        width = window.innerWidth;
        height = window.innerHeight;
        target = {x: width/2, y: height/2};

        largeHeader = document.getElementById('large-header');
        largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';

        canvas = document.getElementById('demo-canvas');
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // create points
        points = [];
        for(var x = 0; x < width; x = x + width/20) {
            for(var y = 0; y < height; y = y + height/20) {
                var px = x + Math.random()*width/20;
                var py = y + Math.random()*height/20;
                var p = {x: px, originX: px, y: py, originY: py };
                points.push(p);
            }
        }

        // for each point find the 5 closest points
        for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            var closest = [];
            var p1 = points[i];
            for(var j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {
                var p2 = points[j]
                if(!(p1 == p2)) {
                    var placed = false;
                    for(var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                        if(!placed) {
                            if(closest[k] == undefined) {
                                closest[k] = p2;
                                placed = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    for(var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                        if(!placed) {
                            if(getDistance(p1, p2) < getDistance(p1, closest[k])) {
                                closest[k] = p2;
                                placed = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            p1.closest = closest;
        }

        // assign a circle to each point
        for(var i in points) {
            var c = new Circle(points[i], 2+Math.random()*2, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.3)');
            points[i].circle = c;
        }
    }

    // Event handling
    function addListeners() {
        if(!('ontouchstart' in window)) {
            window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
        }
        window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollCheck);
        window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
    }

    function mouseMove(e) {
        var posx = posy = 0;
        if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
            posx = e.pageX;
            posy = e.pageY;
        }
        else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)    {
            posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
            posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
        target.x = posx;
        target.y = posy;
    }

    function scrollCheck() {
        if(document.body.scrollTop > height) animateHeader = false;
        else animateHeader = true;
    }

    function resize() {
        width = window.innerWidth;
        height = window.innerHeight;
        largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
    }

    // animation
    function initAnimation() {
        animate();
        for(var i in points) {
            shiftPoint(points[i]);
        }
    }

    function animate() {
        if(animateHeader) {
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
            for(var i in points) {
                // detect points in range
                if(Math.abs(getDistance(target, points[i])) < 4000) {
                    points[i].active = 0.3;
                    points[i].circle.active = 0.6;
                } else if(Math.abs(getDistance(target, points[i])) < 20000) {
                    points[i].active = 0.1;
                    points[i].circle.active = 0.3;
                } else if(Math.abs(getDistance(target, points[i])) < 40000) {
                    points[i].active = 0.02;
                    points[i].circle.active = 0.1;
                } else {
                    points[i].active = 0;
                    points[i].circle.active = 0;
                }

                drawLines(points[i]);
                points[i].circle.draw();
            }
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    function shiftPoint(p) {
        TweenLite.to(p, 1+1*Math.random(), {x:p.originX-50+Math.random()*100,
            y: p.originY-50+Math.random()*100, ease:Circ.easeInOut,
            onComplete: function() {
                shiftPoint(p);
            }});
    }

    // Canvas manipulation
    function drawLines(p) {
        if(!p.active) return;
        for(var i in p.closest) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
            ctx.lineTo(p.closest[i].x, p.closest[i].y);
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(156,217,249,'+ p.active+')';
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }

    function Circle(pos,rad,color) {
        var _this = this;

        // constructor
        (function() {
            _this.pos = pos || null;
            _this.radius = rad || null;
            _this.color = color || null;
        })();

        this.draw = function() {
            if(!_this.active) return;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(_this.pos.x, _this.pos.y, _this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(156,217,249,'+ _this.active+')';
            ctx.fill();
        };
    }

    // Util
    function getDistance(p1, p2) {
        return Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2);
    }

})();
```

Works without Meteor, works on jsFiddle, it is just the rendering of the template that provides this bug. Also, if I copy and paste this function in console, and run it, the page renders, but the animation is still not shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to remove the `(function(){ ... }());` .

All this does it call the function as soon you fire the page. This works in normal scenarios, but not in Meteor.

And then wrap these values lie these :

```
while (document.getElementById('large-header') !== null) {
        largeHeader = document.getElementById('large-header');
    }
    largeHeader.style.height = height + 'px';


    while (document.getElementById('demo-canvas') !== null) {
        canvas = document.getElementById('demo-canvas');
    }
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```